why python list doesn't implement __copy__ and __deepcopy__
Unlike Python's array, which implements __copy__ and __deepcopy__ so that the copy module can use it,
Python's list does not implement __copy__ and __deepcopy__. (although there is a copy method)
Instead, the logic related to list copy is implemented in the copy function and deepcopy function of the copy module.
Why doesn't list have __copy__ and __deepcopy__ methods unlike array?

For built-in types like list, copy.deepcopy() knows how to construct a deep copy, and thus list doesn't need its own __deepcopy__() dunder method.
You add a method like that to your own classes if Python needs to do something more than what is defined for the built-in base type it inherits from (like object or list, for example).
Note that this means you should not use the information whether or not a class implements __deepcopy__ as a proxy answer to the question 'can this class be deep-copied?'
Edit: in the comments, you asked again why array didn't get the same treatment as list. I haven't looked at the Python code for an answer, but I suspect this is because list can contain a mix of types, while an array contains a single type. As a result, when copying an array, knowing the content type you could more efficiently copy arrays of that type. You would not want to burden the more generic deepcopy with that logic, and instead can use these explicit methods - especially relevant when deepcopying.

Thank you for your kind reply and comments. I understand why list doesn't need the __copy__ and __deepcopy__ methods. But I'm still not sure why array needs __copy__ and __deepcopy__ methods. Is it because the copy module doesn't know how to copy (deep copy) the array? So why can't I find out?

Since array is implemented in C, I assumed that it was to provide Python with an interface for copy (deep copy) to enable more efficient copying. Is my guess correct?

@YouHoGeon well, list is implemented in C.

I've updated the answer with my thinking on why array doesn't have them - I think that's right, but you could more closely inspect the C source for array to see how things are dealt with in detail. The copy module would 'know' how to copy the array, but for something like an array (often large quantities of the same type) you don't just want a solid and simple 'how', you probably also want some performance, or you could be using a list instead.
